# Help with resizable widgets on Samsung Galaxy S 2?

Tags: app-widgets, samsung-touchwiz, samsung-galaxy-s-2

I'm using the default launcher (TouchWiz 4.0). Some of the widgets can be resized which is great, but unfortunately it seems many others cannot be resized at all.

1. What causes this discrepancy?
2. Is there any other way to resize those seemingly non-resizable widgets?
3. Is there a way to tell in advance whether a widget (for example, one I am seeing on the market) is resizable this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stock Android widgets are not re-sizable (although this is supposedly a feature that will be coming soon). If you can re-size some of them one of two things is going on: either the developer of the widget made it that way, or Samsung implemented this ability to work for some widgets. In the case of the latter they probably had to set it up specifically for the widgets that do it, so it is unlikely that any you find on the market are going to be re-sizable via TouchWiz. However, you do have another option. Launcher pro is a homescreen replacement app on the market; [the paid version](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.fede.launcherproplusunlocker) (yes the free version is misleadingly called launcher pro) offers resizing widgets as one of the added features. To my knowledge that would work for any widget regardless of how the developer made it. So if you're willing to put a couple bucks into it, you can re-size any widget that you want.